# How to make sure a client tells the server that the user has disconnected, regardless of the method used to close the client

Tags: c++, qt

When a user closes the client program on their end by pressing the exit button, a message is sent to the server to let it know that the client has disconnected. However, if the client crashes, or if the user ends the process, or if the user closes the client in *any way other than pressing the exit button,* the server doesn't display the message.

How can I ensure that the server will be made aware of a connection being closed no matter how the connection was closed, while maintaining the uniqueness of the connection (and by that I mean, no matter how the user disconnects, the server will display "[username] has disconnected.")

I am using C++ with the Qt library. I was thinking there would be a signal that would let me do what I want, but I haven't found one.

Comment: If the client program is ended abruptly and unexpected, how could it possibly continue to execute to close the connection in a nice manner? Instead you might need to implement some sort of keep-alive mechanism, with timeouts, to see if a connection is up.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So maybe something like periodically sending a request to the client from the server, and if I receive no response in some time, then I can disconnect the client?

Comment: Yes something like that. And that can be used by the client at well: If the client haven't received this special request from the server in some time, then the server is probably gone and the client should reconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Qt, I assume that you're using [QTcpServer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTcpServer.html). In this case, when a new connection occurs you get back the [QTcpSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html)* from calling [nextPendingConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#nextPendingConnection)().

When the client disconnects, either cleanly or abruptly, if you've connected to the signals [disconnected](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#disconnected)() and [error](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error)() of the [QTcpSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html), you will be notified when the disconnection occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `QIODevice::readChannelFinished()` signal on the server side to detect that the connection was closed. It doesn't matter by which means the client has closed the connection. This can serve as a last resort to react on client crashes on the server side.

To actively notify from the client side, it depends on the type of application. If you have a GUI-application, you could connect the `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()` signal to be notified that the application is closed in a normal manner.

A console application is harder to handle, as there are no Qt methods to catch all possibilities. On Windows, you could install a [Console Control Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx). This will react on closing the command box, Ctrl-C, etc.